# Python syntax help

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I write code for dictionary, so that it prints like this ?
**{"one":1, "two":2, "three":3}** как можно написать код в цикле, чтоб он печатался вот так ?

**one two three \n 1 2 3**

тоисть в верхнем части слова, а нижнем части цифры

Answer (score 2):

Получить ключи словаря можно методом `keys`, а значения — методом `values`.

***Пример:***

```py
d = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
print(*d.keys())
print(*d.values())
```

***stdout:***

```html
one two three
1 2 3
```

***UPD:***

```py
values = []
for key in d:
    print(key, end=' ')
    values.append(d[key])
print('')
print(*values)
```

Comment: @user367426 Цикл должен быть один? Можно ли после него исполнять какие-то инструкции печати?

Comment: ну конечно, как можно без печати печатать что то

Comment: только без употребление каких либо функции

Comment: @user367426 Я задал Вам 2 вопроса, но Вы ни на один не ответили :D. Да и вообще, у Вас довольно странные требования... Может, Вам подойдёт обновлённый вариант?

Comment: такие решении я тоже знаю, просто скажите есть способ с end="" аргументом печатать так чтоб получилось или нет ?

Answer (score 0):

Извращенский способ, но красивый вывод :)

```py
from itertools import chain


def print_dict(d: dict) -> None:
    max_len = max(map(len, map(str, chain(d.keys(), d.values())))) + 1
    frmt_str = "{{:<{}}}".format(max_len)
    keys_line = ""
    values_line = ""
    for key, value in d.items():
        keys_line += frmt_str.format(key)
        values_line += frmt_str.format(value)
    print(keys_line, values_line, sep="\n")


print_dict({"one":1, "two":2, "three":3})
```

Вывод:

```
one   two   three
1     2     3
```

Comment: :) ну нет, зачем все это)) не будем мучить же сам себе

Comment: и да цикл должен быть один

Comment: end="", sep="", \n, такие аргументы конечно можно написать, но я попробовал все, не получается никак, и по моему так не может быть как я понял

Answer (score 0):

Решение через создание двух отдельных строк для ключей и значений:

```
def print_dict(d: dict):
  (keys, vals) = ("", "")
  for key, val in d.items():
    keys += str(key) + " "
    vals += str(val) + " "
  print(keys)
  print(vals)
```

Пример выполнения:

```
>>> print_dict({"one":1, "two":2, "three":3})
one two three
1 2 3
```